# Função JQuery funciona no console, mas no arquivo não funciona

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel

Então, estou usando uma biblioteca de carousel Jquery (Owl-carousel) e alguns elementos como por exemplo esse trecho abaixo:

```
<div class="owl-dots"><button role="button" class="owl-dot active"><span></span></button><button role="button" class="owl-dot"><span></span></button><button role="button" class="owl-dot"><span></span></button><button role="button" class="owl-dot"><span></span></button></div>
```

São rendereziados no meu código fonte, contudo eu queria adicionar um atributo atraves do `setattribute()` nas classes `.owl-dot` e fiz a seguinte função:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.owl-dot').each(function(){
        this.setAttribute('arial-label','Button slide');
    });
});
```

Porém quando insiro essa função na console do devtools ele funciona normalmente, porém quando adiciono esta função no meu documento ele não funciona. Vi alguns tutoriais falando para usar a função `ready()` para quando todo o o HTML carregar a função ser executada.

Comment: Veja em qual ponto do html está sendo carregando o arquivo jquery.js. Observe se não está carregando no final da página

Comment: @donardo Ele estava sendo chamado no `<head>` , testei colocando antes do fechamento da tag `<body>` e também não deu certo.

Comment: Não precisa colocar "resolvido" no título. Sei que é comum em muitos fóruns, mas aqui funciona diferente. No seu caso, como vc mesmo encontrou a solução, basta usar o campo de respostas abaixo (o textarea "Sua Resposta"), e depois [marque-a como aceita](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/112052), isso já é o suficiente para indicar que foi resolvido.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conseguir resolver, em vez de usar o `ready()` usei o `(window).load` que só é disparado quando todo o conteúdo é carregado (incluindo imagens, vídeos, etc).

```
jQuery(window).load(function () {
    jQuery('.owl-dot').each(function(){
        this.setAttribute('arial-label','Button slide');
    });
});
```